# Converting string to date using R

Tags: r, fresco

How can I convert string"15081947" to a valid date format "1947-08-15" using R?
[image]

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you think it didn't work. See ["What Have You Tried?"](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) for an excellent article that you may be interested to read. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't upload code or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0):

Very handy is the lubridate package. There it would be e.g. `dmy("15081947")`.